# Javascript code does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a panel activated/deactivated with a checkbox (chk1)'On/Off'. This panel contains a checkbox (chk2) and a radio button (rbtn).
When the radio button (rbtn) is checked the checkbox must be disabled.
When the panel is disabled by unchecking the 'On/Off' checkbox, the radio button and the checkbox (chk2) are disabled.
The problem is that when I open the page with panel enabled, the code from javascript is executed, but when I open the page with panel disabled, after I enabled the panel the javascript doe not work when I check the radio button so that the chk2 became disabled.

```
 $(document).ready(function (){
     $('input[id^=rbtn]').click(function () {
         SetControlEnableState($('#chk2'), $('#rbtn'));
     });
     function SetControlEnableState(controlToSet, control) {
         if (control.is(':checked')) {
            $(controlToSet).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            alert('if');
         }
         else {
            $(controlToSet).removeAttr('disabled');
            alert('else');
        }
     }
});
```

When the panel is updated the javascript code is not available anymore.

Comment: you are using jQuery.Did you imported jQuery files

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error or isn't your code behaving as expected?

Comment: No error appears, but I put alert messages in function SetControlEnableState and the message was not show.

Comment: How do I import jQueryfiles?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the `click` event on checkboxes but the `change` one :

```
    $('input[id^=rbtn]').change(function () {
```

This way you'll get the new state. The `click` event is generated *before* the checkbox is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
$(controlToSet).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$(controlToSet).removeAttr('disabled');
```

Do this:

```
$(controlToSet).prop('disabled', true);

$(controlToSet).prop('disabled', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function (){

            $('input[id^=rbtn]').change(function () {
                SetControlEnableState();
            });
    function SetControlEnableState() {
        if ($('#rbtn').is(':checked')) {
            $('#chk2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            alert('if');
        }
        else {
            $('#chk2').removeAttr('disabled');
            alert('else');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify the whole thing:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('input[id^=rbtn]').change(function () {
         SetControlEnableState($('#chk2'), $('#rbtn'));
     });

     function SetControlEnableState(controlToSet, control) {
         controlToSet.prop('disabled', control.is(':checked'));
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('input[id^=rbtn]').click(function () {
        SetControlEnableState($('#chk2'), $(this));
    });
    function SetControlEnableState(controlToSet, control) {
        if (control.is(':checked')) {
            $(controlToSet).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(controlToSet).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }
});
```